# $.extend with second paramter as function

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables, extend

I have the below code:

```
$.extend($.fn.dataTable.defaults, {
  "height": 500,
});
```

It's working fine, but I want to make this conditional for few datatables, so I thought to put second parameter as function which returns an object, like the below:

```
$.extend($.fn.dataTable.defaults, function() {
  // check datatable condtion and reurn
  return new {
    "height": 500,
  }
});
```

I am not able to make that work. How can I set a few default properties depending on datatable id?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

`$.extend()` expects an object. The error is because it's trying to use the function reference you provide as an object, which clearly won't work. To fix this, execute the function and provide the response to the argument. To do that add `()` after the function definition to execute it immediately.

Also note that the `new` keyword is not needed when creating an object.

```js
var foo = { 
  width: 100,
  height: 100 
}
var output = $.extend(foo, function() {
  return { height: 500 }
}()); // note the () here

console.log(output);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

However, it should be noted that this is a very contrived situation. If you can define the function at that point you could just create an object instead and avoid the ugly syntax.

Alternatively, if the call is to an externally defined function, this will work by default:

```
var output = $.extend(foo, someExternalFunctionThatReturnsAnObject());
```

Comment: How i can find jquery datatable id